# Chart Not Loaded in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi I have just loaded a xlsx file with graph,but the graph is not displayed in output.

This is my **code :**

```
 $objPHPExcel=$objPHPExcel_new = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("../Graph_sample.xlsx");



$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('result.xlsx');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.Actually my loaded xlsx file having datas.In result i seems only datas graph does not appear.

Answer (score 7):

Because most users don't want to load charts by default (loading/saving charts is a speed and memory overhead), you have to explicitly tell PHPExcel that you want to load them using `setIncludeCharts()`:

```
$objPHPExcel=$objPHPExcel_new = new PHPExcel();
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("../Graph_sample.xlsx");
```

and when writing

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save('result.xlsx');
```

Comment: Thanks mr.Mark. Iam also try these but it returns a error             "Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_StringTable::writeRichTextForCharts() must be an instance of PHPExcel_RichText, array given, called in"  .And also return a alert  unreadble file before open xlsx file

Comment: In that case, you've found a bug in the code: something in the chart definition that cannot be processed correctly. Please can you provide an example of a template that demonstrates this problem to the phpexcel development team via the codeplex issues page so that it can be investigated